# Problems adding new string values to subKey

Tags: vb.net, registry

I'm not able to add string values into a subKey. I have no problem creating the sub key, just can't add an item to the subKey. Below is an example...

```
 regKey = My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Test subKey")

        My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Test subKey", "TestValue", "This is a test value.")
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something basic. Also, I have tried to get it to work for hours now without any luck.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `RegistryKey` returned by `CreateSubKey` to set the value. 
Additionally close the key after writing so the value is flushed to registry:

```
Dim reg As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Test subKey")
reg.SetValue("TestValue", "This is a test value.")
reg.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. However, your code is doing the same thing as mine. It creates the subKey just fine, but it's not adding "TestValue". At least that's what is happening on my computer.

Comment: Hm it worked for me: [image](http://s7.postimg.org/xz3g5zq2z/2016_01_22_16_06_23_Registrierungs_Editor.png). 
But ... I have used `Microsoft.Win32.Registry` instead of My.Computer.. can you try if it works for youe?

Comment: I tried: Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("testSubKey") but with no luck. However, I can't even create the subKey in my way or yours. The reason is probably because I have so much code commented out and don't remember which one works. I need to get back to where I started.

Comment: Yea! I got it working. Finally got your code to work for me. Then once it was working, I just changed the values into what I needed. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: You´re welcome. Do you mind setting the question as answered? Thanks.

Comment: I haven't done this in a while. Do I answer my own question and give you credit there?

Comment: You just click the grey checkmark beneath my answer and it will turn green, credit us both :)

Comment: I'm having a bit of a problem. I don't see a grey checkmark.

Comment: [like this](http://s23.postimg.org/sw2b6rnfv/2016_01_22_18_06_43_c_Group_by_optional_colum.png) :)